# Creating complex request to site (public transport company) in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, json, httpwebrequest

**What I'm trying to do:**

I wanted to play with gps data provided by my local public transport company (MPK Wrocław) in my WPF app. But unfortunately there is no public API but there is a working example on official MPK site: 
http://pasazer.mpk.wroc.pl/jak-jezdzimy/mapa-pozycji-pojazdow

So basicaly what I need to do:

- create request to: "http://pasazer.mpk.wroc.pl/position.php"
- set method to "POST"
- set content to "json" or "application/json" (don't know which, they are kind of the same)
- fill data - create query

On official site it's done by:

```
function ajaxData() {
    var x = {bus:[],tram:[],train:[]};
    for (type in busList) {
        for (i in busList[type]) {
            x[type][x[type].length] = jQuery.trim(i);
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

and then:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseBusPosUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'busList':ajaxData()}, // <-- there is query
}) 
[do something with response]
```

**What I have:**

```
[class MPKPositioner and some other code]

private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

public WebResponse GetPositions(string line)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestUrl);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "json"; //"application/json"

    string query = "{busList[bus][]=" + line.ToLower() + "}";
    byte[] byteArray = GetBytes(query.ToLower());

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    return request.GetResponse();
}
```

Usage:

```
MpkPositioner positioner = new MpkPositioner();
Print(positioner.GetPositions("a"));
```

**What's wrong:**

```
Header:
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 22:20:29 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17



Response:
```

So as you can see there is no data in response.
I know that in web browsers that can be caused by same-origin policy (you can't get json data from another domain) but this time I don't use browser.

Is there something wrong? Or did I just forgot something.
I can add that I can make simple request to other website like microsoft.com

Comment: BTW. There is example (I hope it's working - I have not tested):
https://github.com/niedakh/pozycjoner/blob/master/mpk.py

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed setting your ContentLength property on the request object. See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx  for reference.